# If a helper stack almost completely deletes after problem is solved, what is the space complexity?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, space-complexity

I'm solving the "valid parentheses" leetcode question (#20) and I ran into this solution that seems very efficient - it uses a helper stack that usually ends up being completely empty if the parentheses are all valid.

I was wondering if the space complexity would be around O(N) or less? I'm confused mostly because the helper stack is usually deleted at the end, but I'm aware this would not be the worst-case scenario, so I'm not really sure.

This is the code:

```
class Solution {
    
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '(')
            stack.push(')');
        else if (c == '{')
            stack.push('}');
        else if (c == '[')
            stack.push(']');
        else if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != c)
            return false;
    }
    
    return stack.isEmpty();
    
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If the worst case would be a string full of `(`, then your stack size would be N (the length of the string). So its space complexity is O(N).

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: By the way, `s.toCharArray()` is O(N) by itself, because you're creating a new array of N characters.

Comment: ohh, so the time complexity would be 2  * O(N) --> O(N) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused mostly because the helper stack is usually deleted at the end

It's not what ends up with the stack at the end, but rather what's in the stack *during* the processing. Imagine a string `((((((()))))))` (a valid parenthesis sequence). Even though the stack would be empty at the end, it will contain N/2 characters midway through the solution, i.e. O(N/2) which is O(N) in asymptotic complexity.

Also bear in mind that usually the best case scenario is not very useful. I would imagine a best case scenario would be `()()()` where at any time you have only 1 character in the stack. But because we rarely care about the best case, we want the worst or expected case, which is O(N).

So the answer is simply O(N).